# How to deterimine at runtime if Twitter framework is available?

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

I have an app that uses sharekit to submit stuff to Twitter. I want to take advantage of Twitter framework and be able to do a test runtime that if Twitter framework is not available, use the old way.

How would I get about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see if your user is on iOS 5 and has the native Twitter API available, try:

```
if([TWTweetComposeViewController class] != nil) { /* tweet here */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways I have used to determine if the Twitter application is installed, or you can send a tweet:

### 1.

```
- (BOOL)isTwitterInstalled { 
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]]; 
}
```

### 2.

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) 
{
    // Yes, you can send a tweet.
}
```

You can also see if the iOS version is greater than 5.0, which is when the Twitter framework would be available.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: Add tweeting capabilities to your iOS 4 app with [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController).

Open source. Mimics TWTweetComposeViewController. Works with iOS 4 and later.